# Does Paypal Sandbox Update Business Account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the PayPal sandbox for the first time.  I created a buyer account, a seller account and a form using the directions on their site.

Now, I can pay using the form and the payment does get deducted from the buyer's account.  However, the balance does not increase in the seller's account. Is this how the sandbox works? Or should I assume that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You should see the transaction in your account overview. What does it say under 'Payment Status'?

Comment: I went to account overview in the buyer's account and under recent activities I see that $5 has been deducted.

Comment: I did everything from scratch again.  Setup two brand new accounts and submitted the form.  This time it went through. I thing the sandbox is a little buggy.

Answer (score 2):

> the balance does not increase in the seller's account. Is this how the
>   sandbox works? Or should I assume that I am doing something wrong?

The Live and Sandbox PayPal environment both do the same thing. If a payment is sent to an email address that is not confirmed on that PayPal account, it will not increase the balance of the PayPal account, nor be associated with that PayPal account, until the email address is confirmed.

When this happens, you should look at the buyers account, and pay special attention to the email address the payment was sent to. If that is the correct email then I would guarantee it is not confirmed. If it is not the correct email, that is the problem. Typos are very common when people are trying to link PayPal up to their store, I've seen it many times.

To prevent any issues with confirming email addresses in the sandbox, you should use preconfigured accounts which do all of the following

1. Automatically add financial information
2. Confirm email addresses
3. otherwise verify accounts
4. Get your account open in less than 10 seconds

Comment: can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835944/paypal-sandbox-business-account-not-credited-and-buyer-is-not-debited

Comment: I took a look and was going to help out but PP_MTS_Chad (he knows his stuff) got to it first.