# Paypal sandbox buyer account not debited and seller account not credited using [Client Side Express Checkout using REST]

Tags: javascript, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

The issue is that PayPal sandbox buyer account not debited and seller account not credited using [Client Side Express Checkout using REST]

Similar question exists but it is using different approach: [Paypal Sandbox Business Account not credited and Buyer is not debited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835944/paypal-sandbox-business-account-not-credited-and-buyer-is-not-debited)
So not useful in this case.

Below is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
        client: {
            sandbox:    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            production: '<insert production client id>'
        },

        // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
        commit: true,

        // payment() is called when the button is clicked
        payment: function(data, actions) {

            console.log(data);
            // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '5', currency: 'USD' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            console.log(data);
            // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                window.alert('Payment Complete!');
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');

</script>
</body>
```

**If I check Sandbox API call history it shows the call:**

[image]

**I am checking debit and credit here, it is always same.**

[image]

**This is the response I am getting after payment:**

[image]

```
{paymentToken: "EC-9KH619457W604780E", payerID: "QDUVETXZHS6Q6", paymentID: "PAY-5EM20515GN939974CLILPZ7Q", intent: "sale", returnUrl: "http://localhost/?paymentId=PAY-5EM20515GN939974CL…&token=EC-9KH619457W604780E&PayerID=QDUVETXZHS6Q6"}
```

Comment: If anybody does not have an answer, can somebody tell me that I am doing it right or wrong? I mean is this a normal way to implement PayPal checkout and if we receive paymentID in response then does that mean payment done?